# Cannot edit basic Mapbox JS GL example code

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

```
<div id='map' style='width: 400px; height: 300px;'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'TOKEN';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: '<your HTML element id>',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location
    center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
</script>
```

I have this code working with my custom style, but anytime I try to modify it, the page turns blank. If I change the center, the zoom, or the width or the height, nothing shows up. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It's my first Mapbox attempt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the modified code that is not working please? The code that you have provided is incomplete.

Please try out the below code to display a map. Please ensure to replace <ACCESS_TOKEN> with your access token:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Display a map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location
        center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 9 // starting zoom
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, using that code it works when modified. I have no idea why. Thanks for the help!